Unable to Retrieve Key-Value Pairs from HashVariableSupportedMapImpl in Joget Plugin Configuration
I’m developing a custom Badge Formatter plugin for Joget DX8 that applies Bootstrap badge classes to values in a datalist based on user-defined conditions. The conditions are set in a grid within the plugin configuration, where each entry includes two fields: value (to match the datalist value) and badge (the Bootstrap badge class to apply).
I retrieve these conditions using getProperty("conditions"), which returns an array of HashVariableSupportedMapImpl objects. However, I’m having trouble accessing the key-value pairs ("value" and "badge") from these maps. The log output shows that the condition map contains {undefined=Approved}, and both condition.get("value") and condition.get("badge") return null.
Here’s the relevant log:
INFO  Processing value: Approved
INFO  Conditions array length: 1
INFO  Condition map: {undefined=Approved}
INFO  Checking condition: Value=null, Badge=null
INFO  Condition values are null or missing, skipping.


I’m using the following code to loop through the HashVariableSupportedMapImpl[] array:
if (conditionsObj instanceof HashVariableSupportedMapImpl[]) {
    HashVariableSupportedMapImpl[] conditionsArray = (HashVariableSupportedMapImpl[]) conditionsObj;

    for (HashVariableSupportedMapImpl condition : conditionsArray) {
        String conditionValue = (String) condition.get("value");
        String conditionBadge = (String) condition.get("badge");

        if (conditionValue != null && conditionBadge != null) {
            if (conditionValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(result.trim())) {
                badgeType = conditionBadge.toLowerCase();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


I also verified that the conditionsObj is correctly retrieved as an array, but for some reason, the keys value and badge return null.
I expect to access the "value" and "badge" keys from each HashVariableSupportedMapImpl object and apply the correct badge type when a condition is matched. However, the current implementation shows the keys as undefined and the values as null. How can I properly access the key-value pairs from these HashVariableSupportedMapImpl object?
